# getJSON in jquery & json_encode in PHP & headers

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, header, jsonp

I have this php file(courses.php) in a separate domain.

```
<?php
header('content-type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8');

 $array = array();
 $array[0]["id"] = "1";
 $array[1]["id"] = "2";
 $array[2]["id"] = "3";

 $array[0]["coursename"] = "Course Name 1";
 $array[1]["coursename"] = "Course Name 2";
 $array[2]["coursename"] = "Course Name 3";


echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

I use JSONP to access the data like below in the localhost.

```
$.getJSON( 'http://example.info/mobile/courses.php?callback=?', function( result ) {
       console.log(result);
});
```

It does not work. But if I change the URL to twitter like below it works

```
$.getJSON( 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=dogs&callback=?', function( result ) {
       console.log(result);
});
```

According to my knowledge it should be the `courses.php` file. But I have no clue how to fix this.

What could be the issue? How can I fix this?

Comment: Twitter response headers is `Content-Type application/json;charset=utf-8`

Comment: Just so you know, even if you fix this issue, any day now Twitter will be shutting down this part of their API as it is deprecated, and this will no longer work. To make it work visit the following plugin page and take a look at the examples and setup instructions (you will have to modify the example PHP code to use the search API, but, other than that, it is the same): http://zkniebel.github.com/jquery-twitter-feed/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script does not return JSONP, but JSON. The response for JSONP is a JavaScript "file" with one function call, where the function name comes from the `callback` parameter.

So instead of just returning

```
{"bar": 42}
```

you have to return

```
foo({"bar": 42});
```

Include the function name in your output:

```
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($array) . ');';
```

You probably also want to use some sensible default if `$_GET['callback']` is not present, or simply return JSON then. This is useful if you don't need or can use JSONP (e.g. calling the URL from another server side script).

---

Note: The name "JSONP" is a bit misleading, because the technique does not actually have anything to do with JSON. The response your generate is pure JavaScript code and you could pass anything to the function call, it does not have to be an JSON-encoded-and-as-object-interpreted data structure (it can be any valid JavaScript data type).

Comment: if you can please explain a bit more because your details are really helpful.

Comment: What should I explain more? Maybe this helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP.

Comment: I mean like why should we the callback method name with the results?

Comment: Because that's how JSONP is "defined". It is what makes JSONP JSONP. Otherwise it's just JSON.